# How do I get property type through xpath

Tags: xml, eclipse, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

How do I get the Data Type of the property using xpath. My code is below

```
 <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('poNumber')=INTEGER">
```

I also need to check if the property is empty. See the code below

```
<filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('poNumber')=''">
```

And this is my property

```
<property expression="$url:poNumber" name="poNumber" scope="default"
type="INTEGER" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

I am sending `poNumber` as a url param, and have to check if the property value is provided or not. If it is, I have to check if its an Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with regex.

```
<filter source="$url:poNumber" regex=".*\S.*">
    <then>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value is " value="Not Empty"/>
        </log>
        <filter source="$url:poNumber" regex="-?\d+">
            <then>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="Value is " value="Integer"/>
                </log>
            </then>
            <else>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="Value is " value="Not Integer"/>
                </log>
            </else>
        </filter>
    </then>
    <else>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value is " value="Empty"/>
        </log>
    </else>
</filter>
```